# TextView Shadow Offscreen Rendering

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` containing `Fragment`s, each containing a single `TextView`. I'm creating a parallax effect by calling `TextView.setShadowLayer(...)` to an offset based on the position of the `TextView` on screen. It all works great, but has one hiccup. The `TextView`s each have two lines of different lengths (center gravity), and as each line moves off screen, that line's shadow also disappears abruptly. It creates an effect where the two lines of the same `TextView` have shadows that disappear abruptly at different times, when I want them to stay visible until the shadow itself is off screen.

I'm pretty sure it's something specific to `TextView` due to the shadow disappearing based on the line and not the overall view position. Is there a way to force `onDraw()` even when a `View`, or a line of `TextView` is off screen?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can try it out?

Comment: have you tried adding a padding to those textViews? 
which android version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant call `onDraw()` when until the view is visible but it can be done on unity using some thing like `culling`.

besides that just to give a shadow to the TextView you should use a backgound image with a little transparency.

Hope it help:)